# algorithm for nth_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, median, nth-element

I have recently found out that there exists a method called [nth_element](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/nth_element.html) in the STL. To quote the description:

> Nth_element is similar to
>   partial_sort, in that it partially
>   orders a range of elements: it
>   arranges the range [first, last) such
>   that the element pointed to by the
>   iterator nth is the same as the
>   element that would be in that position
>   if the entire range [first, last) had
>   been sorted. Additionally, none of the
>   elements in the range [nth, last) is
>   less than any of the elements in the
>   range [first, nth).

It claims to have O(n) complexity on average. How does the algorithm work? I could not find any explanation for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's called a selection algorithm and wikipedia has a decent page on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Also read about order statistics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the median-of-medians algo.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_.22Median_of_Medians_algorithm.22