# How to get the second largest number by not usings list and max()min()

Tags: python

I want to find the second largest number such as this topic. [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time)

My problem is this restricting words `list`, `[]`, `remove`, `del`, `min`, `max`, `dict`, `{}`, `sort`, `pop`.

I have no ideas to get the second largest number. Then, I want someone to suggest me.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not using a list then where are you storing the numbers??

Comment: `print sorted(lst)[-2]` may be. Though I don't understand `don't use the list` part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we find second maximum from array efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392689/how-can-we-find-second-maximum-from-array-efficiently)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I've understood correctly your question but the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time) you've mentioned is giving you already few good solutions. For instance, if you don't want to code the algorithm by yourself, use the standard library [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) like this:

```
import random
import heapq

random.seed(1)
el = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(20)]
print el
first_max, second_max = heapq.nlargest(2, el)
print "Max element is {0} and the second max {1}".format(first_max,
second_max)
```

Comment: `heapq` functions operate on lists, which he or she _can't_ use.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_max=arr[0]
second_max=first_max
if(arr[0]>arr[1]):
    first_max=arr[0]
    second_max=arr[1]
for i in range(1,len(arr)):
    if(arr[i]>first_max):
       second_max=first_max
       first_max=arr[i]
    elif(arr[i]>second_max):
       second_max=arr[i]

print(second_max)
```

I think above code will work for all cases... try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
a = [1,5,7,8,3,4,6,8,2,9]
x=-999999999999
n=999999999999
for i in a:
    if i>x:
        x=i
for i in a:
    if x-i!=0 and x-i<n:
        n=x-i
        ans=i
print ans
```