# finding the maximum number in array

Tags: c, algorithm

there is an array of numbers an this array is irregular and we should find a maximum number (n) that at least n number is bigger than it (this number may be in array and  may not be in array )

for example if we give 2 5 7 6 9 number 4 is maximum number that at least 4 number (or more than it ) is bigger than 4       (5 6 7 9 are bigger)

i solve this problem but i think it gives time limit in big array of numbers so i want to resolve this problem in another way
so i use merge sort for sorting that because it take *nlog(n)*  and then i use a counter an it counts from 1 to k if  we have  k number more than k we count again for example we count from 1 to 4 then in 5 we don't have 5 number more than 5 so we give k-1 = 4 and this is our n .

it's good or it maybe gives time limit ? does anybody have another idea ?

thanks

Comment: `(this number can be in array and can not be in array )` well I suppose you want to say `(this number may be in array and may not be in array )`

Comment: qsort and then count backwards as far as you want eg. 4 in this case

Comment: it still not solved .i want to know this way (using merge sort and counter ) is good or not

Comment: Did you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 5):

In `c++` there is a function called `std::nth_element` and it can find the nth element of an array in linear time. Using this function you should find the `N - n`- th element (where `N` is the total number of elements in the array) and subtract 1 from it.

As you seek a solution in `C` you can not make use of this function, but you can implement your solution similarly. `nth_element` performs something quite similar to qsort, but it only performs partition on the part of the array where the n-th element is.

Now let's assume you have `nth_element` implemented. We will perform something like combination of binary search and `nth_element`. First we assume that the answer of the question is the middle element of the array (i.e. the N/2-th element). We use `nth_element` and we find the `N/2`th element. If it is more than `N/2` we know the answer to your problem is at least `N/2`, otherwise it will be less. Either way in order to find the answer we will only continue with one of the two partitions created by the `N/2`th element. If this partition is the right one(elements bigger than `N/2`) we continue solving the same problem, otherwise we start searching for the max element `M` on the left of the `N/2`th element that has at least `x` bigger elements such that `x + N/2 > M`. The two subproblems will have the same complexity. You continue performing this operation until the interval you are interested in is of length `1`.

Now let's prove the complexity of the above algorithm is linear. First `nth_element` is linear performing operations in the order of `N`, second `nth_element` that only considers one half of the array will perform operations in the order of `N/2` the third - in the order of `N/4` and so on. All in all you will perform operations in the order of `N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1`. This sum is less than `2 * N` thus your complexity is still linear.

Your solution is asymptotically slower than what I propose above as it has a complexity `O(n*log(n))`, while my solution has complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: +1 this is a fairly trivial algorithm to implement. The thought experiment of quicksort partitioning only into the partition holding the index of the desired element for each sub-sequence is literally spot-on.

Comment: i want to use C . can you tell a little how solve this problem ?

Comment: @storm-saeed I understand and that is what I address in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @storm-saeed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2392485/812912) deals with specifics on how to implement the algorithm, but in essence the logic is as I explain

Comment: for example i give 1 2 3 4 5 how solve this with your algorithm ? the answer is 2

Comment: Sorry but I doubt your conclusion of time complexity. It is true that the average time of `std::nth_element` is `O(n)`, so what about the next move? I don't get your idea that how can you use a single (or a constant number of times) call of `std::nth_element` to solve this problem. Please explain. Thx.

Comment: My answer is wrong, because it seems I have missunderstood the question. Complexity is linear but I have to add more to my answer, I will add it right away.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev You're not alone on the not understanding the question thing. Is the OP literally asking to supply their own pivot *value* rather than an n-th element index? If so, yeah, that would clearly be a different issue.

Comment: @starrify I have edited the answer adding more details on how do we use what I propose to find the maximum `n` for which at least n elements are bigger in linear time.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thank you. This time I can get your idea. :D

Answer (score 0):

I would use a modified variant of a sorting algorithm that uses pivot values.

The reason is that you want to sort as few elements as possible.

So I would use `qsort` as my base algorithm and let the pivot element control which partition to sort (you will only need to sort one).